# Deleted /usr/ folder fully and cannot boot into os

Tags: boot, 18.04

Hi I by mistake deleted all contents of /usr/ as a result I can't boot in to my linux. And the error code  I am getting when tried recovering mode is 0x00007f0.

I have many important documents and codes there.

I do not have my live usb with me now so I can't take backup and reinstall it.

Please help thank you

Comment: Welcome, sadly your OS is beyond repair, but your data is not lost. You **need** a pendrive with a live Ubuntu and presumably an external disk to backup you data, or, depending the size, in the cloud.

Comment: How to backup data

Comment: Oh wait a min i haven't deleted full /usr/ I just deleted the `x86_64_gnu_linux` folder or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Create a live USB on another computer and use it to boot the one you have broken. You may also try to remove the hard drive from your computer and connect it to another, working Linux computer to access data on it.
There are no other options.